# Passing $_SESSION in php

Tags: php, session

Currently been at this for  few hours now and desperately need a fresh set of eyes. When log in takes place a form is loaded to test encrypted password and username against the database, as it stands there are no errors showing up in the form when it is run but simply when it is run it denies the data from the user currently in the database being passed through.

I also recieve the final else statement giving me "Access Denied" any help would be hugely appreciated just need a fresh set of eyes, thanks alot. also to add all the $data instances are fields within the database

```
<?php
$serverName = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databaseName = "filestackusers";
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$serverName;dbname=$databaseName",$username, $password);
//encrypt pass and user for search
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
{
$FolderEncryption = md5($_POST['username']);
$passwordEncryption = md5($_POST['password']);
}
else
{
    echo "information not passed";
}


try
{
    //search if found load info
    $checkSqlStmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_folder =
   :FolderEncryption AND password = :passwordEncryption");

    //bind
    $checkSqlStmt->bindParam(':FolderEncryption', $FolderEncryption, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $checkSqlStmt->bindParam(':passwordEncryption', $passwordEncryption, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    //execute
    $checkSqlStmt->execute();

    $data = $checkSqlStmt -> fetchAll();

}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    die("An error has occured! " . $ex->getMessage());
}

if ($data)
{
    if($_POST["username"] == $data[0]["username"]) //recheck email security
    {
        echo 'Access Granted';

        $_SESSION['userID'] = $data[0]['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['Username'] = $data[0]['username']; //set sessions
        $_SESSION['Password'] = $data[0]['password'];
        $_SESSION['Email'] = $data[0]['email'];
        $_SESSION['UserFolder'] = $data[0]['user_folder'];

        //load user info
        loadFileInformation();
    }
}
    else
    {
        echo "Access Denied";
    }
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php may be helpful.

Comment: Where is `session_start()` ?

Answer (score 4):

You only echo `access denied` when $data evaluates to false. That can be the case when you don't assign it at all, which happens when you get an exception when executing the query. If there is no exception, fetchAll might still return false in case of an error.

But also, if the query executes correctly but returns no rows, `fetchAll()` returns an empty array, which also evaluates to false in PHP. (I don't make this stuff up!)

So whichever the case, it is due to the execution of the query.

Comment: Thats the thing the query selects all rows from table users where user_folder = encrypted path ad pass = encrypted path so it should give me back the row of data for the user in theory but it just isn't, is there any simple way to echo what it is giving back?

Comment: You can `var_dump($data);` right after the call to `fetchAll()` that should give you the type and the value of the data, so you'll see instantly whether it's an empty array, false or any other value. If it is false, you can use the methods `errorInfo` and `errorCode` of the statement to get additional information about the error.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that your `$data` variable is false so your code is echoing `"Access Denied"`. You should set your condition to check that $data equals what you want it to and then proceed.

For Example:

```
if ($data == "Blah"){ 
  if($_POST["username"] == $data[0]["username"]) //recheck email security
  {
     //Blah Blah
  }
}else{echo "Access Denied";}
```

As opposed to:

```
if ($data)
{
    if($_POST["username"] == $data[0]["username"]) //recheck email security
    {
      //Blah Blah
    }
 }else{echo "Access Denied";} // etc
```

The point is that your condition should be more precises. Whether using `fetchAll` or what ever.

Comment: is that not what i have done here? if($_POST["username"] == $data[0]["username"])

Comment: Before you get to that, you have a prior conditional statement